# Composer use private fork of a repository

Tags: git, github, composer-php, git-fork, ccxt

This question is clearly answered in other places, but it simply does not work for me. I can also see a lot of people have problems with this.

I am trying to use a fork of CCXT (branch name is `bitmart`) in my own project as it contains some major changes which have not yet been merged with the original `ccxt/ccxt`

git version: 2.20.1
composer version 1.7.2

My composer file in my project looks like this:

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@github.com:devsi/ccxt"
}],
 "require": {
    "ccxt/ccxt": "dev-bitmart as 1.18.409"
}
```

I've tried the https url : `https://github.com/devsi/ccxt` and it still does not work.

I have tried removing the version constraint and instead it tries to read every single version release ever in CCXT. The processing time would take hours. It does about 1 per second.

```
Reading composer.json of ccxt/ccxt (1.17.378)
Reading composer.json of ccxt/ccxt (1.17.377)
Reading composer.json of ccxt/ccxt (1.17.376)
```

and so on.

When specifying a version, the error I receive is:

```
Failed to clone the git@github.com:devsi/ccxt.git repository, 
try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                               
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:devsi/ccxt.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-devsi-ccxt.git/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can clone it without a problem, I've been using it for weeks so I don't think its related to credentials.

Comment: I think composer requires the github access to be configured separately:
- https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/managing-composer-github-access-personal-access-tokens
- https://www.google.com/search?q=composer+github+oauth+key

Comment: @IgorKroitor somehow you always end up helping me! Either on CCXT, Email or StackOverflow. So this works, however it still ends having to read every version of CCXT ever released. I'm watching it now and its stepping back from 1.18.409, one release at a time. one a second. It'll probably have updated my vendor in a few hours....

Comment: I have submitted my fork to Packagist for now and am using it directly. (renamed the package, and removed keywords so I don't get searched so often). Unless I figure out why composer isn't letting me pull a fork, this will have to do temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone else who finds this problem. My fork of the repository was up to date with the latest version of the original source. However, the tags were not. As git fetch does not fetch the tags, when synchronizing your fork and the source, make sure you also `git fetch upstream --tags` and `git push --tags` to bring the releases up to date too. Without this I was given an obscure warning about credentials and failing to execute git clone. The real error was:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                            
  Could not find a version of package devsi/ccxt matching your minimum-stability (dev)
```

This also explains why it was reading every version one by one. It could never find the version it needed as it wasn't available in the forked repo.

Once the tags were up to date. the VCS method worked.